# How to slide image/content vertically after clicking the arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I normally use slick carousel: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/ to slide image/content horizontally after clicking the arrows.

Now I need to slide image/content vertically after clicking the arrows (just like image). But I couldn’t customize it.

Could anybody here to help me to customize it or suggest anything else for sliding image/content vertically after clicking the arrows?

See the image for better idea:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Read the API for the plugin, there is a vertical option for it.

Comment: Yes, look at the last settings option: `vertical boolean false Vertical slide mode`.

Comment: Hi **ralph.m** and **drip**, I am happy to say that I could apply it successfully according to your advice. Keep well.